# What does it mean - TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to pass a function that I define using the lambda keyword into a plotting function, but I get TypeError message. The relevant piece of my code is this :

```
y = lambda z: dot_epsilon(z) * (math.exp(-tau(z))/H_z(z).value)
plot(y,100, 5e6)

def plot(function, min_x, max_x):
    t = np.logspace(min_x, max_x, 1000)
    s = function(t)
    plt.plot(t, s, 'b-', lw=2)
```

I get this error message:

```
  File "mucalc.py", line 160, in <lambda>
    y = lambda z: dot_epsilon(z) * (math.exp(-tau(z))/H_z(z).value)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Whay does this TypeError stands for in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `math.exp`, which accepts only a float. Use `np.exp` instead.

This is because `math.exp(x)` trys to call `x.__float__()`, and if `x` is a `np.ndarray`, it's `__float__` is implemented something like this:

```
def __float__(self):
    if len(self) is 1:
        return self.flatten()[0]
    else:
        raise TypeError, 'only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'
```